# ASP.NET Core claims

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, claims

I create project with two methods - cookies one for "admin" and for "normal" user.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlite().AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>();
    services.AddSession();

    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddCookie("owncms", options => { options.LoginPath = "/OwnCMS/Login"; options.Cookie.Name = "owncms"; })
        .AddCookie("main", options => { options.LoginPath = "/Auth/Index"; options.Cookie.Name = "main"; });

    services.AddMvc(
          option => {
              option.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
              option.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
          });
}
```

Process login where check credentials and create claims and create sign in.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login([FromBody] UserLogin userLogin)
{
    string hash_password = Crypto.EncryptString(userLogin.Password);
    Users user = databaseLogic.Users.Where(x => x.Login == userLogin.Login && x.Password == hash_password).FirstOrDefault();

    if (user != null)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Login),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator"),
            new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.UserId, user.ID.ToString())
        };

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims,"owncms");

        var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
        };

        var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

        HttpContext.SignInAsync("owncms", new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authProperties);

        return Json(new { status = true });
    }

    return Json(new { status = false, message = "Login not posible" });
}
```

When I try to read the claims

```
var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims
```

always I get empty claims.

I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1.

Comment: " cookies one for "admin" and for "normal" user." - this won't work with ASP.NET Core's built-in authx cookies and processes. Just use a different set of claims in the stock ASP.NET Core stock cookie - and don't try inventing your own auth.

Comment: `AddCookie("owncms"` <-- This is incorrect. The first argument to `AddCookie` is the ASP.NET Core **authentication scheme name**, not the cookie-name - and ASP.NET Core's cookie auth schema only supports a single named cookie at-a-time.

Comment: Re: `Crypto.EncryptString` - does this method hash/digest the input, or does it encrypt it? If it encrypts it, then you should be hashing it instead. If it's hashing it then you should rename the method to `HashString`, not `EncryptString`. Also you should be using salted-hashes. Also, SQL string comparisons are case-insensitive by default so you've unintentionally _halved_ your security by doing that.